# Elution and void volumes in a gel chromatography experiment

Tags: analytical-chemistry, chromatography

I was using gel-filtration for separation Hb from xylene cyanol FF with Blue Dextran to determine the void volume. Sephadex G-25 is stationary phase, and mobile phase was buffer $(\pu{0.020 mol dm-3}$ $\ce{Na2HPO4}$ and $\pu{0.150 mol dm-3}$ $\ce{NaCl},$ $\mathrm{pH} = 7).$

Is it possible that my sample has smaller elution volume than void volume?

Comment: I took a liberty to correct spelling, formatting, capitalization (use genuine compound names) and wording (don't mix your native language with English) to make the question more understandable, but still it's rather hard to comprehend what is being asked. What is Hb? Hemoglobin? "*Is it possible that my sample has smaller elution volume than void volume?*" — how did you come up with this conclusion? Feel free to [edit] your question to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Blue dextran (molecular weight is about in a range of $\pu{5\!- \! 2,000  kDa}$, according to [the manufacturer](https://tdblabs.se/products/blue-dextrans/)) is used in affinity chromatography, gel filtration chromatography, protein chromatography and molecular weight markers. Blue dextran is a collection of molecules of dextran to which a blue dye (Cibacron blue F3GA) is covalently attached (Ref.1 & Ref.2):

[image: Blue Dextran]

Most of the molecules of dextran are so large and so irregular in shape that they cannot penetrate the beads (of Sephadex G-25 here) at all, but there may be some of the blue dextran molecules that are smaller and elute at a volume greater than the void volume. The volume at which the first peak of $\mathrm{A_{620}}$ from the blue dextran emerges from the tubing is the void volume, $V_\circ$, of the column plus any volume between the bottom of the stationary phase (Sephadex G-25 here) and the end of the tubing feeding the fraction collector.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemoglobin#:~:text=The%20subunits%20are%20structurally%20similar,studied%20of%20the%20hemoglobin%20molecules):

> In adult humans, the most common hemoglobin type is a tetramer (which contains four subunit proteins) called hemoglobin A, consisting of two $\alpha$ and two $\beta$ subunits non-covalently bound, each made of 141 and 146 amino acid residues, respectively. This is denoted as $\alpha_2\beta_2$. The subunits are structurally similar and about the same size. Each subunit has a molecular weight of about $\pu{16,000 Da}$, for a total molecular weight of the tetramer of about $\pu{64,000 Da}$ $(\pu{64,458 g/mol})$. Thus, tetramer of hemoglobin-A ($\alpha_2\beta_2$) would have larger elution volume (enter the pores) than the $V_\circ$ measured by blue dextran (which would not enter the pores of Sephadex G-25).

For comparison, $\beta$-amylase (Theoretical Molecular weight: $\pu{223.8 kDa}$)would elute first after Blue dextran with an elution volume little greater than $V_\circ$.

**References:**

1. John E.Wilson, "Applications of blue dextran and cibacron blue F3GA in purification and structural studies of nucleotide-requiring enzymes," *Biochemical and Biophysical Research Communications* **1976**, *72(3)*, 816-823 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0006-291X(76)80206-9).
2. David Viet, Stephanie Beck-Candanedo, Derek G. Gray, "Synthesis and characterization of blue dextrans," *Carbohydrate Polymers* **2008**, *74(3)*, 372–378 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.carbpol.2008.03.003).